# How to show horizontally div overflow in next line using css

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I am trying to show the horizontally overflow div in the next line but it is not working.
Div1 width is 66% but div1's div is like display flex. So it is going to the horizontally. Not coming in the next line. How to show the overflow div in the next line.

Demo: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-g2hrgx?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.css

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kNkaL.png)

```css
.div1 {
  height: auto;
  min-height: 125px;
  width: 66%;
  border: 2px solid #ccc
}

.div2 {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-container-element {
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
  grid-gap: 0px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  min-width: 97.5px;
  height: 32px;
  margin-left: 12px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
}

.grid-child-element-1 {
  margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 7px;
  width: 23.4px;
}

.grid-child-element-2 {
  margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 7px;
  min-width: 64.35px;
}

.grid-child-element-3 {
  margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 24px;
  font-size: 7px;
  width: 23.4px;
}

.text {
  font-size: 7px;
  margin: 0px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
  min-width: 23.4px;
}

.num {
  font-size: 7px;
  margin-top: 7px;
}
```

```html
<div class="div1">
  <div class="div2">
    <div class="grid-container-element">
      <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-2">
        <div class="text">Div 2Div </div>
        <div class="num">1234</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-3">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="grid-container-element">
      <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-2">
        <div class="text">Div 2Div </div>
        <div class="num">1234</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-3">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="grid-container-element">
      <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-2">
        <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Div 2 </div>
        <div class="num">1234</div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-child-element-3">
        <p>text</p>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-container-element">
        <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-2">
          <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Div v 2</div>
          <div class="num">1234</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-3">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-container-element">
        <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-2">
          <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Di 2Div 2</div>
          <div class="num">1234</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-3">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-container-element">
        <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-2">
          <div class="text">Div 2 2Div 2</div>
          <div class="num">1234</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-3">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="grid-container-element">
        <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-2">
          <div class="text">Div 2Di Div 2</div>
          <div class="num">1234</div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-child-element-3">
          <p>text</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```css
.div1 {
        height: auto;
        min-height: 125px;
        width: 66%;
        border: 2px solid #ccc;
      }

      .div2 {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
      }

      .grid-container-element {
        grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
        grid-gap: 0px;
        border: 1px solid black;
        min-width: 97.5px;
        height: 32px;
        margin-left: 12px;
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
      }

      .grid-child-element-1 {
        margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 7px;
        width: 23.4px;
      }

      .grid-child-element-2 {
        margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 7px;
        min-width: 64.35px;
      }

      .grid-child-element-3 {
        margin: 3px 1px 1px 1px;
        border: 1px solid red;
        height: 24px;
        font-size: 7px;
        width: 23.4px;
      }

      .text {
        font-size: 7px;
        margin: 0px;
        word-wrap: break-word;
        min-width: 23.4px;
      }

      .num {
        font-size: 7px;
        margin-top: 7px;
      }
```

```html
<div class="div1">
      <div class="div2">
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Div</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Div</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Div 2</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Div v 2</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Div 2Di 2Div 2</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2 2Div 2</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-container-element">
          <div class="grid-child-element-1">Div 1</div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-2">
            <div class="text">Div 2Di Div 2</div>
            <div class="num">1234</div>
          </div>
          <div class="grid-child-element-3">
            <p>text</p>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
```

so first, you forgot to close a div, and then you just have to add flex-wrap: wrap; and it will work.